# Make a function(with graph) at the interval $[a,b]$ satisfying Lagrange Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

Make a function (with graph) at the interval $[a,b]$ which has exactly

a) $2$ points satisfying Lagrange Mean Value Theorem

for example $x^3$ at interval $[-2,2]$ (checking points $A(-1,-1)$ and $B(2,8))$.

b) $3$ points.

For $b$ I can't bring example, and for $a$ is my example right?

Comment: What does it mean "2 points satisfying lagrange mean value theorem over an interval $[a,b]$" in your opinion?

Comment: for example $x^3$.$A(-1,1)$ and $B(2,8$.We have two points $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ that satisfy lagrange mean value theorem meaning tangent lines passing through this points are parallel to $AB$.

Comment: You are probably checking the interval $[\color{red}{-1},2]$. In that case it doesn't make sense to talk about the derivative at the point $x=-1$. Further a point that satisfies the MVT must be an interior point of $[-1,2]$ which $-1$ is not.

Comment: Then what examples would fit for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: When you make the interval $[-2,2]$ the slope of secant is $4\ne f'(-1),f'(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regards your example for a), given $f(x)=x^3$ and the interval $[-2,2]$ then we have to find the number of points $t\in(-2,2)$ such that
$$\frac{f(2)-f(-2)}{2-(-2)}=f'(t)\Leftrightarrow 4=3t^2\Leftrightarrow t=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\in(-2,2).$$
Exactly two points! So your example is correct, but then the *checking points*, i.e. the points where the tangent lines are parallel to the secant line, should be $A=(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},f(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}))$ and $B=(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},f(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}))$.

Hint for the general case. Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ over the interval $[0,n]$ where $n$ is a positive integer.
Now count the number of points $t\in(0,n)$ which satisfy Lagrange Mean Value Theorem, that is
$$\frac{f(n)-f(0)}{n-0}=f'(t).$$